# Why catalina.home_IS_UNDEFINED directory is generated by Logback in the same project directory?

Tags: java, tomcat, playframework-2.0, logback

I have written logback configuration file for my application, but when I was doing maven clean install(mvn clean install), it generated a catalina.home_IS_UNDEFINED directory with log file in the project directory.
Why this directory generated ?

I don't want it to be in my project directory.

Any help to address this issue ?

Here is the configuration file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<configuration>

    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5p [%t] %c{1} - %m%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="MY_APP_LOG" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${catalina.home}/logs/myApplication.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <FileNamePattern>${catalina.home}/logs/myApplication.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</FileNamePattern>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%-5p  %date{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %m%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <append>true</append>
    </appender>

    <logger name="org.springframework" level="WARN"/>


    <root>
        <priority value="INFO"/>
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="MY_APP_LOG"/>
    </root>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 14):

## Background

This property load fails because it is filled only by tomcat. It is not filled by the **maven compile task.**

## Solution 1

Set property like this in logback.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <if condition='isDefined("catalina.home")'>
        <then>
            <property name="log.folder" value="${catalina.home}/logs"/>
        </then>
        <else>
            <property name="log.folder" value="./target/logs"/>
        </else>
    </if>

    <appender name="companyMyAppServiceAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>${log.folder}/company.myApp.log</file>
        ...
    </appender>

    ...

</configuration>
```

This will create log files at target folder at compile time that will be erased with clean.

## Solution 2

"Rewrite" value:

```
<property name="log.folder" value="./target/logs"/>
<if condition='isDefined("catalina.home")'>
    <then>
        <property name="log.folder" value="${catalina.home}/logs"/>
    </then>
</if>
```

### NB!

And do not forget to import maven janino dependency

```
<!-- The org.codehaus.janino:commons-compiler:2.7.8 dependency -->
<!-- will be automatically pulled in by Maven's transitivity rules -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
    <artifactId>janino</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.8</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 7):

I would suggest not relying on the janino dependency (1 MB for nothing in this case) there is a simpler solution using the logback's default value implementation like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <property name="base.folder" value="${catalina.home:-./target}"/>

    <appender name="MY_APP_LOG" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${base.folder}/logs/myApplication.log</file>
        ...
    </appender>

    ...

</configuration>
```

Look for the `:-` characters beetween the variable name and the default value.
If the `${catalina.home}` variable is empty the default value (in this case `./target`) will be used.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem and determined that it was caused by my unit tests lacking a proper Tomcat environment.

My minimal solution was to add the following `src/test/resources/logback.xml` to my Maven project directory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <property name="catalina.home" value="target" />
</configuration>
```

Logs generated by the unit tests then ended up in the `target` directory rather than the top level directory of the project.

Answer (score 2):

```
<file>${catalina.home}/logs/myApplication.log</file>
```

During server(tomcat) startup. Logback API tries to substitute ${catalina.home} variable in logback.xml with the environment variable, usually -Dcatalina.home java environment which usually equals CATALINA_HOME, set by tomcat "catalina.sh" internally .

You need to check your tomcat "catalina.sh" or "catalina.bat" if the Environmental variables i.e "catalina.home" is set up properly or not.

"catalina.home_IS_UNDEFINED" means Logback could not replace it with any System or environmental Variable.

Answer (score -4):

Try to change:

```
<logger name="org.springframework" level="WARN"/>
```

to:

```
<logger name="org.springframework" level="OFF"/>
```

Comment: It creates %catalina.home directory. ??

Comment: Wait, what is your aim here? Where do you want those logs?

Comment: Actually , I want to build application using maven, when I do mvn clean install, it generates the war file, which I want to deploy on tomcat.Now the issue is when I am building the application, it generates unnecessary directory in my project directory mentioned above.

Comment: OK so check my edit, to completely turn off logging.

Comment: but it did not solve my issue still the same directory generated.